# How do I generate a temporary token for someone to post to my S3 account?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html#setting-getting-the-access-control-list-for-buckets-and-keys

I'm using boto.

My friend says it's possible to just generate a temporary (expires in 5 min?) token so his iphone client can post to my S3.

How can I do that with boto?  I'm reading the documentation and don't quite get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

I used boto.key's generate_url.